# Any Search Extension which does the 2 word job for Magento Yet?

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento since its days of birth has the worst search engine and I can't imagine, how Magento core team has ignored this completely. We are now at 1.9.x and its still the same. 
No improvement or work whatsoever.

I have seen every commercial search extension now too, none tell to work the more than one keyword search results, CORRECTLY!

So, has anyone got a solution yet or any good working extension ?

Let us know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fast search engine you must use a search server. many plugins for magento were developed during these years. you can find plugins for:

- AWS Cloud Search -> http://www.magefinder.de/ (free)
- Elasticsearch ->  http://www.bubbleshop.net/magento-elasticsearch.html (free/paid)
- Sphinx -> http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/search-search-sphinx-ultimate.html (paid)

and the solr implementation made in magento Enterprise Edition.

lots of possibilities.